# Summation of terms based on given data

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

> $ \sum_{k=1}^n {\delta}_k=  3^n-1$
>
> then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{\delta_k}= $

I tried writing the reciprocal terms and taking lcm but it isnt feasible since there are infinite terms

Comment: Did you find what the $\delta_k$ are?

Comment: $\delta_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \delta_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \delta_k$

Comment: Just "guessing": $\displaystyle
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\,\,\,2\left(3^{k- 1}\,\,\right) = 3^{n} - 1\ \stackrel{\LARGE ?}{\implies}\
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\,\,\,{1 \over 2\left(3^{k- 1}\,\,\right)} = {3 \over 4}\qquad
$

Comment: @FelixMarin didn't get it though